# java count words in string

Tags: java, string, count, words

I was writing code to find number of words in string and the code is as below:

```
package exercises;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class count {

    public static int countwords(String str){
        int count=0;
        String space="";
        String[] words=str.split(space);
        for(String word:words){
            if(word.trim().length()>0){
                count++;
            }

        }
        return count;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Enter the string");
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    String s=input.nextLine();
    System.out.println(countwords(s));

    }

}
```

and for doing practise I wrote this code once again as

```
package exercises;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class count {

    public static int countwords(String str){
        int count=0;
        String space="";
        String[] words=str.split(space);
        for(String word:words){
            if(word.trim().length()>0){
                count++;
            }

        }
        return count;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Enter the string");
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    String s=input.nextLine();
    System.out.println(countwords(s));

    }

}
```

I am just wondering why is the output of the code different for this codes? though I checked the codes line by line I cant find the reason why the output of these two codes are different? can anyone please help

Comment: You lost me at `str.split("")` ... why would you want to split on empty string, rather than a space (or whitespace)?

Answer (score 2):

Since your splitting string is `""`, every letter will be extracted as a word.

Just change `String space="";` to `String space=" ";` or `String space="\\s+";`, and you're good to go!

The regex tool `\\s+` indicates that the string should be split after one or more occurrences of a space.

Comment: Thanks that works.Also any suggestions to make this code better ? also what has to be added to find unique and duplicate words in the string.

Comment: @ppkumar Anytime :)

Answer (score 0):

```
String space="";
```

is wrong. It's an empty string and will be used wrong.

You better use

```
     String space="\\s+";
```

or

```
    String space=" ";
```

The regex "\\s+" is "One or more whitespace symbol"

Comment: Don't you mean "\\s+"?

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be something like that :

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter the string");
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    String line=input.nextLine();
    System.out.println(Arrays.stream(line.split(" ")).count());
}
```